# Using OR in if statement to see if either query param present

Tags: python, django, rest, filtering, query-string

I am looking to implement a simple filter using a single query param (eg `age=gt:40`, `name=eq:bob`).  I am wondering if it is possible to check if either `name` or `age` is present in the GET request at once?  An example might clarify what I'm after:

```
if ('age' or 'name') in request.GET:
```

This will only match when the first one is used.  When I hit the endpoint with the query param `name` it doesn't match true.

I know I could do something like:

```
if ('age' in request.GET) or ('name' in request.GET) :
```

but this could grow quite quickly and become ugly.

Comment: `('age' or 'name')` itself evaluates to `'age'` before the `in` operator is used.

Comment: Is it possible that `'age'` and `'name'` could *both* be present? (I.e., what exactly is `request.GET`?)

Comment: No, not in my use case, it'll be one at a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**`any(…)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(x in request.GET for x in ('age', 'name')):
    # …
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is it possible to access which value matched within the if?

Comment: `any((witness := x) in request.GET for x in ('age', 'name'))`. `x` is local to the generator expression used by `any`, but `witness` is created in the same scope that `any` is called in.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use set intersection:

```
if {'age', 'name'}.intersection(request.GET)
    ...
```

It is slightly less efficient than `any` (no early stopping), but IMO it's more readable

Comment: `set(('age', 'name'))` -> `{'age', 'name'}` :)